# The best way to say the mentioned meaning?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> A intentionally keeps B ignorant of C.

Now I want to say that the above form of behavior is not morally acceptable.

The sentence I have in mind is something like this:

> A's intentional keeping ignorant B of C is not morally acceptable.

I know that the above sentence is problematic. What is the correct way to say it, if we want to keep my sentence structure as long as possible?

Comment: [A's] intentionally keeping B ignorant of C is etc.

Comment: Why not simply "A intentionally keeps B ignorant of C, which is not morally acceptable."

Answer (score 1):

> A intentionally keeps B ignorant of C.

You could choose one of these (or some other word), depending on the situation. *Keep* on its own already supplies the meaning that something is done intentionally. *Withhold* and *obscure* are more specific:

- keep

> I will **keep** it a secret.

*Keep in the dark* is a colloquialism that expresses more clearly what you mean in this situation. It means that you are keeping something a secret, but it places some unspoken judgment on whether or not that is the proper thing to do:

> Alice: Didn't you tell him?
>
> Bob: No, I'm keeping him in the dark for now.

== I'm keeping it a secret (although that might not be the proper thing to do) for now.

Here is your original sentence:

> A's intentional keeping ignorant B of C is not morally acceptable.

You might translate this to using *to keep in the dark* in this way:

> A's keeping B in the dark about C is not morally acceptable.

Or, more conversationally it might be expressed like this:

> It's unacceptable that A is keeping B in the dark about C.
>
> (or)
>
> A is keeping B in the dark about C. That's unacceptable.

- withhold

This sounds more formal than keep.

> Do not withhold important information from the detective.

- obscure

This means that you are intentionally making something hard to find or hard to understand. It may be an underhanded way of 'keeping' something from someone.

> I wrote down my phone number, but I obscured the digits so that the clerk would have trouble making them out.